# There was no endpoint listening WCF rest service?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, wcf-rest

I am calling a service to retrive product list but when it readched for retrieving list it gives exception:

> There was no endpoint listening at that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

My c# code is as

```
  ProductRestService.ProductRESTServiceClient pro = new ProductRestService.ProductRESTServiceClient("ProductRestService");
  var prodcuts = pro.GetProductList(); //Generating exception here
```

The client service model is

```
<system.serviceModel> 
      <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
          <binding name="WebHttpBinding_IProductRESTService" />
        </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <client>     
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:1175/ProductRestService.svc/" binding="webHttpBinding"  behaviorConfiguration="web" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_IProductRESTService" contract="ProductRestService.IProductRESTService" name="ProductRestService" />
      </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and my service web.config is as:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.ProductRestService"
               behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="ProductRestService" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IProductRESTService"
              behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
    </service>
    </services>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/> 
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Any idea please how to solve this!**

Comment: Is there anything in the InnerException?

Comment: @user1069816 i checked and the inner exception is null

Comment: If you navigate to http://localhost:1175/ProductRestService.svc/ do you see a page?

Comment: @user1069816 yes it is navigating

Comment: Have u checked your query will it return a value ?

Comment: Why are you you trying to call a RESTful service like a SOAP service?

Comment: In client config try endpoint address="http://localhost:1175/ProductRestService.svc/ProductRestService", i.e. add endpoint name at the end.